# Error : "Failed To Execute Skype Backend Request Get Thread S2SRequest " while Adding MSTeam Members to the Private channel

Tags: microsoft-teams, private, channel, private-members

I am Trying to Add Team Members to the Private channel in MS Teams For that I am Getting this Error ”Failed To Execute Skype Backend Request  Get Thread S2SRequest ”,

I created Ms Team First Added 4 Team Members to the Teams after that i created Private channel and Trying to Add 2 members out of 4 Team Members .

I am using the Same Access token for Creating the Project ,Channel and Adding team Members to the Private Channel , and For Now I am giving “Owner” role for All Team Members .

I am using this  Doc to Add team Members to the channels

“ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http “

Any one have idea or Solution for this Will be Helpful

[image: 1]

Thank you

Comment: Have you added the proper permissions? How are you acquiring token? By delegated or application?

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes I have added proper permission Channel member .Read write All,By Application,I am retriving tooken from authRequest/DirectoryOrTenantID

Comment: Still facing this Issue

Comment: Have you followed this document: [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0)?

Comment: Check token in any decoder such [JWT.io](https://jwt.io), if you are getting proper permissions.